# How to add different css to last image in a line with out knowing how many images there might be

Tags: wordpress, image, lines, word-wrap, nextgen-gallery

I'm in the throws of creating a wordpress page for my photography work. I'm using latest wordpress and latest nextgen gallery plugin.  However I have a css question

I want my page to be responsive my theme is but I need to get nextgen css to be also.  What I would like do is find out following

I have a number of images in a line nextgen css means than spacing between each image is done via L shape padding on the right and bottom see simple diagram below.  This is fine however it also applies this to the last image of the line which I don't want as this does not make margin around the document equal

```
┌──┐░┌──┐░┌──┐░┌──┐░
│  │░│  │░│  │░│  │░
└──┘░└──┘░└──┘░└──┘░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
```

This would be fine if on every device there were a set number images in a row as I already have a worked around this via css & php.  However to be responsive and fit better on smaller device screens the number of images per line might change so I was wondering if there was some way to fix this using CSS.

I managed to do this if I know the number in advance by telling php to use a different div on the 4th image.

At the moment my page is not live so cannot provide a link to it sorry;

Any help gratefully received

Answer (score 2):

It should be as simple as this:

```
.picture-container :last-child
{
    // css for last image here
}
```

where .picture-container is whatever element contains the picture elements.

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
.picbox:last-of-type {
    // css for last image here
}
```

Comment: If you liked this answer, click the checkmark to the left :)

Comment: Thanks for that reply i have looked at both of these.  However they seem to apply they are the last item so is this last item of a row or last item of the list in which case if I've got 16 images in 4 rows would image 4,8,12,16 be  affected or just image 16.  I need this to apply to each row.

Comment: In which case you would use the first example with the name of the row containers. This is the only way to accomplish what you want with pure CSS.

Comment: I was wondering if I could use the overflow:hidden; value to so that extra padding space just over laps the rest of the margin rather than css deciding it's took big for the space and putting it on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten my page to work differently as the only way to fix this was using code which is not compliant with ie7